# How to hide geoxml3 markers when loading KML files?

Tags: javascript, geoxml3, geoxml

I have a geoXML3 parser reading (multiple) KML files onto a Google map, and I have the red arrow/markers showing up. Is there any way to suppress them?

```
var myOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.397, -100.644),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map,
        singleInfoWindow: false,
        afterParse: useTheData
    });

geoXml.parse('data/file1.kml');
geoXml.parse('data/file2.kml');
geoXml.parse('data/file3.kml');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to suppress the markers.

1. The simplest is to remove any `<Point>` geometries from the Placemarks in the KML.
2. You can write a post processing function to hide them after they are created
3. You can create a custom createMarker function that doesn't create markers

[Example of hiding markers](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?type=m&filename=us_states.xml)